Future perfect with different modals
When we form the future perfect continuousn we use either "will" or sometimes "shall". Using other modal verbs such as "must or should" would be considered incorrect by standard grammar rules so for instance
I should have done it before he comes
Is simply wrong we should use "will" or "shall". Yet, when I was abroad I heard a native using "should" not "will". Why is that? Am I wrong that we don't use "should" there or was it just a mistake made by that person?

I’m voting to close this question because it is impossible to verify if the OP heard the statement correctly and whether the speaker was indeed  an Anglophone.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43312/should-as-future-perfect-modal

That user posted two "authentic" examples, we can read both of them and the examples use You should have started your tests by then (i.e. next week/ the next interview. There is no verb that follows that uses the present tense, i.e. comes unlike your example.

Your problem is that you focus on one aspect and ignore the other details. Your question focused on "will" vs "should have" and "must have" when the problem is the verb that follows is in the present: PRESENT  I should do it before he comes ✅ PRESENT PERFECT I should have done it before he came ✅

"I should have done it before he comes" is correct if said before 'he comes'.
This is because the secondary definition of 'should' is "what is probable". Effectively, it means "I will probably have done it before he comes"
However, said after the event, it would be wrong. But so would all of your suggested verbs. Because after the event it would be "before he came".

You mean that I can use many different modals verbs instead of "will" for instance "I must have done the work when he arrives". In other words am I allowed to switch "will" to any other modal verb?
